# Incorrect reference

Tags: cross-referencing, links

When I type `\ref{name}` giving the link is on the wrong page.
How do I fix this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{theorem}

\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[chapter]
\begin{document}
\begin{teo}\label{tvi}
text
\end{teo}
... %insert various \newpage
\ref{tvi}
\end{document}
```

Returns incorrect page.

Comment: Please post a full minimal example.

Comment: Does `teo` include a `\refstepcounter`? Otherwise the `\label` might point to the last label-able item (e.g. section) instead.

Comment: You are talking about links, but your code doesn't show you load **hyperref**; also `teo` doesn't exist in standard LaTeX, so you have to show its definition.

Comment: Your revised example works for me (link pointing to the correct page).

Comment: Yes lockstep, but in my file, using latex file.tex thus page is incorrect link.

Comment: The **theorem** package is obsolete, all its functionality is present in **ntheorem**. Apart from this, I don't see any problem and after adding `\lipsum` paragraphs I always get the correct link.

Comment: You mention that the link jumps to an "incorrect page". Do you perhaps have another object using the label `tvi`? You'll know this is the case your log file contains the output "LaTeX Warning: There were multiply-defined labels." near the end.

Answer (score 3):

Your example works fine for me.

- Make sure that your packages are up to date; you can check which version you have by adding `\listfiles` immediately before your `\begin{document}`
- You should generally load the `hyperref` package last; there some exceptions discussed here: [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before)

Answer (score 1):

Your example works fine for me.

- Follow the advice given by [cmhughes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29504/incorrect-reference/29507#29507)
- Did you compile your document at least twice? Check for any rerun warnings in the log-file, e.g.

  LaTeX Warning: Reference `tvi' on page ... undefined on input line 34.

  Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `....out' has changed.

  (rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right

  (rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

  LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

  LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
- Place a `\phantomsection` before `\begin{teo}`.

Where does the link in your example lead to? The page before or after the `\begin{teo}`, to the first page of your document, ...?